# what's the difference between Single Sign On and Federated Sign On for mobile platforms

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

I've got a question about SSO and Federated SO. What is the difference between these two?

What we are trying to accomplish is give user ability to login with their Facebook, Twitter or Linked In account but we also want to save that with our Company ID so we know who they are. We want to link their Company ID with any social platforms they'd like. Inside the Comapny we also would like them to use same identity to login to other company digital assets like websites and other apps. There are various software systems that sit inside the company that user needs to be authenticated against to gain access. Does that sound like SSO or federated SO? Do we need an external vendor for this? What are the standards for those vendors?

I found an article on differences between the two but frankly still don't understand it because the language used is beyond my knowledge level.

http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/difference-sso-single-sign-on-identity-federation/

thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Identity Federation" refers to the ability to accept users that were not authenticated in your systems (e.g. they use Twitter, FB, someone else's Active Directory, etc.)

SSO is the ability to login in once and then access many applications without needing to enter credentials again.

You often achieve SSO through Federation. But you can have SSO without it. (e.g. an Active Directory domain and multiple apps in that domain: you only sign-in once)

Comment: thank you for your answer! In our case we are looking at Unified ID with Federation. We looked into the functionality of carrying user company ID from one app to the other but this is frankly not possible. what does this site use? SSO or its federated?

Answer (score 1):

Both the article and @Eugenio have the right of it.

Since you want to implement this, let me make some practical observations that may help you:

- You want to offer many ways to authenticate to a common identity.

  - A user ID & password into your own directory (Active Directory)
  - A social log-in like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, Yahoo, Live, Baidu, etc.
  - Another identity system from inside your company
  - Another identity system from outside your company, such as a partner or a client company
- Many people use Active Directory for the identity store.
- You will need to give thought to provisioning users in this directory:

  - For employees, this is often when a hire/terminate/promotion event occurs
  - For external users, you can use just-in-time (JIT) registration on first use.
  - All social log-ins return an email address. You can use this to check if a user with this email already exists. If so, you can ask them if they would like to link the accounts.  If so, you can ask for an authentication on the account such as a password or another social log-in already associated with the account.  This will prevent users from accidentally creating a new account when they don't want to.
  - You will want to support several protocols for single sign-on.

    - Internal apps may be able to use Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) and Kerberos.
    - For non-Windows applications, use SAML or WS-Federation for Web applications, OAuth2 for APIs, OpenID or OpenID Connect for social applications. These all support attributes during the authentication and subsequently. This is a way to pass information to your application about the user, such as name & email, roles, and preferences.
- When you add in mobile and cloud applications (SaaS), you will want to have an architecture based on standards that you are aspiring to.  This will allow you to evolve with the trends in social, mobile and cloud.

There are many ways to implement this.

- You can roll your own using open source, although these are sophisticated, complex technologies w/ many options and of course, you own the evolution and maintenance forever.
- Microsoft offers a free product ADFSv2. This is slightly better than open source, but you still have to configure it for each case, it doesn't support all the protocols, and the support is, well, from Microsoft. (Kinda like "free" as in "free puppies".)
- Lastly there are stack vendors and third-parties that offer more complete products and services.

*** Plug type=shameless** 
My company, Ping Identity, does all this, with ease, better than anybody else, and has the best customer service in the world.  Our implementations usually take a couple of hours, sometimes a couple of days.  We offer it both as a product and a service.  This is all we do and we've been doing it for 10 years for 1,000s of customers, big and small.  Check us out at http://www.pingidentity.com
 **/Plug ***